# How to PUT and POST image files to Apache2 using vhosts? (without PHP)

Tags: http, rest, apache2, http-post

I want to simply POST and PUT image files to a server `test.com`, using apache2. This should result in storing the image file at the desired location. Lets say `/srv/web/images/`

What would be a working vhost configuration? Are there any modules that need to be activated? I am using apache2 on an ubuntu 12.04 server.

I think by default this is disabled in apache for obvious resons, nobdoy should be able to write to a server in the default configuration.

I want to simply secure it with http auth ("user1" / "pass1").

All the documentation and questions I find deal with PHP, but I thought should be possible using simply a REST URI and apache2 without PHP or cgi or a C program.

(Note: I am interessted in a solution without webdav  (but I am not sure if the webdav module supports HTTP PUT which would be OK). And this question has got nothing to with forms or browsers, As an example the upload could use the program `curl`.)

Update: I found this message:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-ivy-user/201004.mbox/%3C4BBCA487.8000401@nitido.com%3E

It seems there once was a module mod_put, which is no longer in the repos of ubuntu. And that webdav has built in the functionality of PUT and DELETE.

If so, I am still unable to understand how to do the right VHOST configuration for simple FILE PUT operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think nowadays for this kind of stuff you configure apache with WebDAV.